# How to manually install WTP in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I need to start learning Java EE web development, but I don't have internet connection at home. What should I download and how should I install?

Comment: Just curious, if you don't have internet how are you expecting to download? To answer, you need Java binaries and an application server like Apache tomcat. Get a good book or follow a good tutorial

Comment: From actual computer where I am rigth now :). I've got some good tutorials, all downloaded already, but my eclipse neon installation does not have WTP module/plugin,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F) includes guidance on manual installation.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on it. Currently downloading all the requirements, I'll tell you later how was it... keep in touch